# Eclipse + CDT: Possible to bind key with GDB user-defined command?

Tags: c, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I have defined (using the `define` / `end` syntax) a user-defined command in GDB, running under Eclipse + CDT. I'd like to be able to call this command with a keybinding from eclipse; is this possible? If so, where would I define such a binding?

Answer (score 0):

No, CDT does not support this.